# How to close/end/terminate an accidental "if" in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

So <kbd>tab</kbd> completion is great... unless you're a n00b... and you type the first part of `ifconfig` and then hit <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> real quick... in which case you end up with:

(not actual terminal input)

```
~$ if
> 
> 
>'
> "
> end
> ^C
> 
> )
> ()
> ]
> 
> []
> ]
> ;
> 
> 
> []
> ;aognf'
> 
>
```

What's really weird is <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> didn't even work. I know about quotation marks (which is why that's what I tried first), but that knowledge didn't help.

How can I break out of one of these fat-fingered mistakes next time, without closing the terminal?

Bonus point for answering what is this thing that I've accidentally started doing?

Comment: Is this the stock Unity terminal? Ctrl+C works for me too.

Comment: Yup, it's stock. And ^C has worked every other time I've tried.  My theory is that I'd somehow created a sequence in the if statement that escaped or ignored the ^C. Subsequent trials with if statements in the terminal have all successfully aborted with ^C.

Comment: Very interesting, actually! I took you literally, and typed out the above lines, but I suppose you were paraphrasing then.

Comment: Yeah, that's just a representative sample... sort of ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have started an `if` statement.  The next command is run, and only if it returns a zero exit status (success) are the following commands executed, from the `then` keyword up until the `fi` keyword ("if" backwards).  Like:

```
if true
then
    echo yes
fi
```

Typically one uses the `test` program (AKA `[`) to test various things such as:

```
if [ $somevariable = someword ]
```

or

```
if [ -f /some/file/exists ]
```

A Ctrl-C aborts it fine for me.

Comment: hmm, ctrl-c definitely didn't work for me, and I saw `fi` elsewhere and tried that too, but none of that returned me to the command prompt. I wouldn't be surprised if my subsequent button-mashing got me into a slightly more complex set of nested brackets and quotes than I thought... Now I know what to try next time, though ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> in cases like this.

You've gotten stuck in a bash shell `if` conditional control structure.

This is the output I see:

```
$ if
> 
> '
> "
> sdf
> )
> []
```

<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>

> bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0):

Use `stty -a` to be sure that **intr = ^C**. If it isn't, ^C is just another character. `stty sane` helps me out of terminal confusion. See `man stty`. Here is the first few lines of mine (where ^C does interrupt if....):

```
walt@spong:~(0)$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
...
```

Comment: Nice idea. mHurley, you could also check if ctrl+C works but typing in a facile command (e.g. `echo foo`), then typing ctrl+C.

Comment: Yes, ^C works and has worked for all other things (that weren't otherwise unresponsive), it just didn't in this case. My theory is that I'd accidentally created a sequence in the `if` statement that escaped or ignored the ^C. Subsequent trials with `if` statements in the terminal have all successfully aborted with ^C.